Is there any way to compact the propagation of uncertainty formula in terms of vectors?
The uncertainty associated to $\xi=f(\mathbf x)$ with $\mathbf x\in\mathbf R^n$ is
$$\delta\xi=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x_i}\delta x_i\right)^2}$$
What I was wondering was if there was a nice expression in vector notation that'd make the above more compact. At first I was thinking something related to $\delta \mathbf x\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla\xi$, but I found are more precise but not too convincing notation which would be
$$\delta\xi=||(\delta_i\xi)_{i=1}^n||,$$
where
$$\delta_i\xi=\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x_i}\delta x_i.$$

I don't think the dot product will get you anywhere because you need to get a vector, but the scalar product yields a number.
You could make use of outer matrix multiplication to get what you need by considering $\delta\mathbf{x}$ and $\nabla\xi$ as a vector and a covector (which it is) respectively. A vector is a column vector and the covector is represented by a row vector. Hence you get a matrix product of the kind:
$$
\delta\xi = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\delta{x_1} \\
\delta{x_2} \\
\dots \\
\delta{x_n}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\dfrac{\partial\xi}{\partial x_1} &
\dfrac{\partial\xi}{\partial x_2} &
\dots &
\dfrac{\partial\xi}{\partial x_n}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
With this notion in mind, you may just use the notation of a typical $L_2$ norm:
$$
\delta\xi = 
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\partial\xi}{\partial x_i} \delta x_i\right)^2} =
\|{\delta\mathbf{x} \nabla\xi }\|_2
$$

Thank you Egor, well thought. I think you can simplify even more by using you matrix definiton of $\delta\xi$:
$$\delta\xi=\sqrt{\mathrm{tr}((\delta\mathbf x\nabla\xi)\cdot(\delta\mathbf x\nabla\xi)^\top))}$$

In this case you don’t need the outer product anymore. Since $\delta \mathbf{x} \nabla \xi$ is already a column vector, it suffices to use usual dot product, omitting the necessity to use the trace operator: $\delta \xi = \sqrt{(\delta \mathbf{x} \nabla \xi)^T (\delta \mathbf{x} \nabla \xi) }$
